# Replace | character between the records with a value in a pipe delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, vi

This is my file.

```
NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
abcd|02|abc|cd|12
jake|04|xy|zzb|12
 lau|92||xcx| 56
```

My desired output has to be like this

```
 NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
 abcd|02|abc#cd|12
 jake|04|xy#zzb|18 
  lau|92|#xcx| 56
```

My file had 4 fields and the 3rd col has a pipe delimiter in between the characters like "ice|cream", my requirement is to replace the | field in the 3rd with any value like (#,* or anything). Since this is pipe delimited file i'm unable to replace that particular part of the file exclusively.Any help will be very useful for me..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1;NR>1 && NF>4{ print $1,$2,$3"#"$4,$5 }' OFS='|' file
```

- `NR==1;` - print the 1st record as is
- `NR>1 && NF>4` - check if record has excessive fields
- `$3"#"$4` - implode the 3rd and 4th fields replacing separator with a new char `#`

The output:

```
NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
abcd|02|abc#cd|12
jake|04|xy#zzb|12
 lau|92|#xcx| 56
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Roman, i'm using a korn shell(ksh) is that the reason i'm getting this error"-ksh: awk -F| NR==1;NR>1 && NF>4{ s=$3"#"$4; print $1,$2,s,$5 } OFS=|: not found [No such file or directory]" while i used the soln u provided.

Comment: You could have done it without the extra variable: `print $1,$2,$3"#"$4,$5`

Comment: @valrog, that was for demonstration purpose

Comment: I guess, this command is for bash shell. @Roman , Can you pl confirm if this logic will fit into gnu awk 3.1.7

Comment: @mac_online, I've tested on GNU Awk 4.1.3, but it should also work on v. 3.1.7, I suppose

Comment: Roman, what if my file has 15 fields and this issue happens at the 10th field. then should i change the logic like "'NR==1;NR>1 && NF>15{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10"#"$11,$,12,$13,$14,$15 }'". right?

Comment: That command will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX system. If you're getting an error from running it then you copy/pasted wrong. No, of course you would not keep going listing explicit fields when there's many of them, you'd use 1 or 2 loops.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want a more traditional logic based solution, (and admittedly painfully long-handed ;-/) here is another solution

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
  {
    #dbg print "#dbg:NF="NF;

    # if this record has an extra character
    if (NF>4){
      # loop over all fields
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        # if not the field of interest or last field on line, just print it
        if(i!=3 && i!=NF){
          printf("%s|",$i)
        }
        # else this is the problem field, add the # char
        else if (i==3){
          printf $3"#"
        }
        # else if last field on line, add LF char at end
        else if (i==NF){
          printf ("%s\n",$i)
       }
      }
    }
    # record has correct number of FS chars
    else {
      print $0
    }
  }' dat.txt
```

**output**

```
NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
abcd|02|abc#cd|12
jake|04|xy#zzb|12
 lau|92|#xcx| 56
```

I've added comments to code to explain what is going on.

---

Here it is as a the all-important one-liner ;->

```
awk -F\| '{if (NF>4){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i!=3 && i!=NF){printf("%s|",$i)}else if(i==3){printf $3"#"}else if(i==NF){printf ("%s\n",$i)}}}else{print $0}}' dat.txt
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Just set `n` to the number of whichever field you want to combine with the field after it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==1 { print; next }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sep = (i==n ? "#" : OFS)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? sep : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
abcd|02|abc#cd|12
jake|04|xy#zzb|12
 lau|92|#xcx| 56

$ awk -v n=2 -f tst.awk file
NAME|NUM|ADDR|AGE
abcd|02#abc|cd|12
jake|04#xy|zzb|12
 lau|92#|xcx| 56
```

Comment: Actually, i don't want the pipe("|') between 2nd and 3rd col to get removed. If you look at the 3rd col say for ex  : Ed|11|TX|HOUSE|45  , I need this to be Ed|11|TX#HOUSE|45. Suppose if my rec like : Ed|11||TXHOUSE|45 ,then it has to be changed to Ed|11|#TXHOUSE|45 .

Comment: Take another look at my answer. I'm showing you how to remove the pipe from wherever you want by means of 2 separate examples after the script that each remove the pipe from different locations just by setting the variable `n`. So if you wanted to change the 10th `|` on each line to a `#` you'd just set `n=10`. The first example (with `n=3`) is producing exactly the output you said you wanted from the input you posted. Let me know if there really is an issue.