# Find and Replace Pipe delimiter from field in a pipe delimited file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have had a similar question like this earlier later i've to add more scope to that question but had no idea how to edit it and make it live again. that's why i'm posting as a new Question.

My file is a pipe delimited file.

```
 NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
 ABCD | 04  | GO|OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
 XYZE | 12  | Y|A|HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
 LMNO | 17  | |FACE|B|O|O|K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
 EDDE | 98  | A||M|AZ|ON| | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

My file is as complicated as this is. Our need is to remove the "|" symbol from the WEB field and replace it with a junk value like #,$,& or anything.

The Output has to be:

```
NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
ABCD | 04  | GO#OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
XYZE | 12  | Y#A#HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
LMNO | 17  | #FACE#B#O#O#K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
EDDE | 98  | A##M#AZ#ON# | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

I've tried awk'ing few filters to clear this mess up.nothing seems to find a happy ending. Thank you!
I would like to thank few names who answered my prev question : RomanPerekhrest, Ed Morton,shellter , val rog.

Comment: Is the delimiter always followed and preceded by a space?

Comment: No, its not. they all are tightly packed. just for a better illustration purpose i wrote it that way

Comment: Then how do you know, on a string like `acbd|02|gh|ij|kl|mn|op|qr` where the web field starts and stops?

Comment: the initial question was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960899/replace-character-between-the-records-with-a-value-in-a-pipe-delimited-file

Comment: We are sure about the 2nd field which is "NUM" and about the LOCATION field which is the 4th field, this won't change in the file.Any field that fall between these both fields has to be scrutinized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==1 { outNf=NF; print; next }
{
    end = beg + (NF - outNf) - 1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sep = (i>=beg && i<=end ? "#" : OFS)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? sep : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v beg=3 -f tst.awk file
 NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
 ABCD | 04  | GO#OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
 XYZE | 12  | Y#A#HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
 LMNO | 17  | #FACE#B#O#O#K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
 EDDE | 98  | A##M#AZ#ON# | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

How it works: On the first line the number of fields to be output is the same as the number of fields on that line so it saves that number as outNF. From then on any subsequent line with more than outNF fields has outNF-NF fields starting at `beg` to be combined. So inside the loop it uses OFS between fields from 1 to beg, then from beg+1 to beg+(outNF-NF) it uses # between fields to create one merged output field from the input fields in that range, then it goes back to using OFS between fields.

Comment: this is so far the best soln, i've question. what are we doing in the .awk file. Can you explain me what is going on in that .awk file. i tried to decipher but not really able to catch it up.

Comment: How is the command able to know that the fields to look for is 3 till the last. i know you've declared it as beg=3, but how is it getting to know that it has to check until the last field of the file to find and replace the |.

Comment: for Example, we know the problametic field is #3. how is this command able to track from field 3 till the last field. I don't see any condition in the .awk file that compares each and very field of the file.

Comment: see the explanation I just added to my updated answer.

Comment: Ed, my last question is , How can i be like you who can i attain your level of understanding about linux scripting and file processing tools. I know it's all about constant practice, apart from that is there any other ingredient to it.I'm really impressed the way developers help eachother here.

Comment: I'm still learning constantly and I've been programming for 38 years, a UNIX user (scripting with grep, sed, shell, etc) for 35 years and an awk user for 25 years (I was very reluctant to learn awk since my introductory experiences then were with old, broken awk!). It's just time and practice and being willing to learn the right way to do something even when you have a wrong way that does what you want, which is very common given the many ways to do anything in UNIX!

Comment: Umm. Can somebody explain Ed's awk script in more simpler terms. I'm sorry i'm finding it little hard to understand.

Comment: What's the first statement you don't understand and I'll see if can explain that better then we'll see if there's anything else still hard to follow?

Comment: Imagine this is the record
ABCD|04|GO|OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS

as per ur logic, outnf=nf ie, number of fields to be o/p is same as the num of records on that line.
So , here there are 7 fields, making it 7=7 (outnf=7).

outNf=NF ( outnf=7)
{
end= beg + (nf(7) - outnf(7) ) -1 . ie end = 3 + ( 7 - 7 ) -1

how does this logic work?

Comment: No, outNf is only set when the condition `NR==1` is true. It's not set every time a record is read, it's only set when the **first** record is read. So you can't tell what the value of `outNf` is just by looking at the current record `ABCD|04|GO|OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS` you have to look at the **first** record in the file so if that first record is `NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE` then `outNf` gets set to the value `6` for that and remains that for all subsequent records. You can add `print outNf` and other such debugging statements to the code to trace the values.

Comment: So when the record ABCD|04|GO|OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS is read, outNf=6 while NF=7 and beg=3 so end=beg(3) + (NF(7) - outNf(6)) - 1, i.e. end = 3 + (7 - 6) - 1 = 3, so sep (the separator string to be printed after $i) is only set to `#` when i==3, and it's OFS for all other fields. Any other questions?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. so we found 3 ie end, the field after which the sep string has to be printed. But how will it know that it has to replace only those pipes in the 3rd field. what stops it from replacing the pipes from the 4th field or the 5th field. what i mean is, how is it able to keep a track of the field that it has to replace.

Comment: You're thinking about this wrong. `beg` is the first field number where we use `#` instead of OFS and `end` is the last field number where we use `#` instead of OFS. If line 1 (the header line) is `a|b|c|d|e` then you know you want to output 5 OFS-separate fields (so outNf=5). If the current line is `l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t` then you know you have 9 input fields (NF=9) and so you know you need to squeeze 4 fields (outNF-NF) into 1 before outputting that line by changing the OFS `|` to `#` between those 4 fields. We also have `beg` set to 3 so we know that the squeezing has to start at field 3.

Comment: So where does it stop? We'll, it stops 4 (NF-outNf remember?) input fields after field 3 so the last time the replacement happens is right after input field number beg(3) + (NF(9)-outNf(5)) -1 = 6 so the output for `l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t` would be `l|m|n#o#p#q#r|s|t` because input field 3 (beg) is `n` and input field 6 (end) is `q`. Create a sample input file with just 2 lines and add some prints to the code to dump the values of all the variables being set/used and it should be clear what's happening. You just need to get over a hump of looking at this the wrong way and then it'll be very clear.

Comment: thanks, you helped me so much. I' really owe you alot of knowledge. I really wish you and your loved ones all the best. You saved me man!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==1{n=NF} NF > n {
s=$3; for (i=4; i<=NF-3; i++) {s = s "#" $i; $i=""} $3=s; gsub(/\|{2,}/, "|")} 1' file

NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
ABCD | 04  | GO#OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
XYZE | 12  | Y#A#HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
LMNO | 17  | #FACE#B#O#O#K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
EDDE | 98  | A##M#AZ#ON# | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

Comment: Note that this answer works for given sample data in question and works on converting extra fields in 3rd field only.

Comment: Hi Anubhav.. what is meaning of this "gsub(/\|{2,}/, "|")}" here . can u brief

Comment: what is use "2" in the gsub(/\|{2,}/, "|")}" and why is i = 4 set in the for loop.

Comment: `i=4` since we are grabbing extra fields starting from 4th field onwards. `gsub` function is called after setting each extra column to empty in `$i = ""` and it replaces extra consecutive `|` with single `|`

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution can be:-

```
awk  -F'[[:space:]][|][[:space:]]' '{gsub(/\|/,"#",$3);print $1,"|",$2,"|",$3,"|",$4,"|",$5,"|",$6}' file.txt
```

Explanation:-

```
-F - for field separator here it is space|space
gsub - global substitution in field 3. i.e. every occurance of | will be replaced by #. 
print - just print all the columns separated by "|"
```

output will be:-

```
NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
ABCD | 04  | GO#OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
XYZE | 12  | Y#A#HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
LMNO | 17  | #FACE#B#O#O#K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
EDDE | 98  | A##M#AZ#ON# | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

Answer (score 1):

easy if you do not mind with **Perl**

If it has space; then we can print it by:

```
stackoverflow ❱ perl -F'\s+|\s+' -a -le  'print $F[5]' file
WEB
GO|OGLE
Y|A|HOO
|FACE|B|O|O|K
A||M|AZ|ON|
stackoverflow ❱
```

Since we can modify the `@F` array in **Perl**; thus we can:

```
$F[5] =~ s/\|/#/g;
```

It modifies only this column not others.

And eventually we can print it:

```
stackoverflow ❱ perl -F'\s+|\s+' -lae  '$F[5] =~ s/\|/#/g;print "@F"' file
 NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
 ABCD | 04 | GO#OGLE | EUROPE | EURO | PARIS
 XYZE | 12 | Y#A#HOO | USA | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
 LMNO | 17 | #FACE#B#O#O#K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
 EDDE | 98 | A##M#AZ#ON# | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
stackoverflow ❱
```

---

If your file **has no space**, as someone commented me; then you can spread others columns; modify only that one and join them all together:

```
stackoverflow ❱ cat file2
NAME|NUM|WEB|LOCATION|CURRENCY|PLACE
ABCD|04|GO|OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS
XYZE|12|Y|A|HOO|USA|DOLLAR|SEATTLE
LMNO|17||FACE|B|O|O|K|ASIA|ASIANDOLLAR|HONGKONG
EDDE|98|A||M|AZ|ON||AFRICA|AFDOLLAR|CAPETOWN
stackoverflow ❱ perl -F'\|' -le  '$s=$#F;$e="@F[2..$s-3]";$e=~s/ +/#/g;print join "|", @F[0..1],$e,join "|",@F[$s-2,$s-1,$s]' file2
NAME|NUM|WEB|LOCATION|CURRENCY|PLACE
ABCD|04|GO#OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS
XYZE|12|Y#A#HOO|USA|DOLLAR|SEATTLE
LMNO|17|#FACE#B#O#O#K|ASIA|ASIANDOLLAR|HONGKONG
EDDE|98|A#M#AZ#ON#|AFRICA|AFDOLLAR|CAPETOWN
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple **awk** solution :

```
awk  -F "|" '{printf $1} 
{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if(i>3 && i<NF-2)printf "#"$i; else printf "|"$i } printf "\n"} ' file

NAME|NUM|WEB|LOCATION|CURRENCY|PLACE
ABCD|04|GO#OGLE|EUROPE|EURO|PARIS
XYZE|12|Y#A#HOO|USA|DOLLAR|SEATTLE
LMNO|17|#FACE#B#O#O#K|ASIA|ASIANDOLLAR|HONGKONG
EDDE|98|A##M#AZ#ON#|AFRICA|AFDOLLAR|CAPETOWN
```

`if(i>3 && i<NF-2)` : this condition is for extra unwanted fields after 3rd field and before NF-2nd field. If it satisfies, prefix "#" before printing these extra fields.

Comment: @mac_online: This works with/without spaces. A simple generic solution.

Comment: Hi, wow this is also good one. May i know why you set i=2 inside the for loop

Comment: In the for loop the fields are printed in this fashion [operator][value] i.e values prefixed by operator "#" or "|".  I've printed the first field before for loop because it doesn't require a prefix and then using for loop from 2nd field to last one for our desired logic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to put this in one line, but rather made it a little easier to read.  Those who play [perl golf](http://perlgolf.sourceforge.net/) will be able to reduce it considerably.  The idea is to anchor the first two fields and the last three.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  if(($name, $num, $web, $location, $currency, $place) = $_ =~
     /^([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|(.+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)$/) {
    $web =~ tr/\|/\_/;
    printf "%s\n", join('|', ($name, $num, $web, $location, $currency, $place));
  }
}
__DATA__
 NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
 ABCD | 04  | GO|OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
 XYZE | 12  | Y|A|HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
 LMNO | 17  | |FACE|B|O|O|K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
 EDDE | 98  | A||M|AZ|ON| | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

Output:

```
 NAME | NUM | WEB | LOCATION | CURRENCY | PLACE
 ABCD | 04  | GO_OGLE | EUROPE | EURO   | PARIS
 XYZE | 12  | Y_A_HOO | USA    | DOLLAR | SEATTLE
 LMNO | 17  | _FACE_B_O_O_K | ASIA | ASIAN DOLLAR | HONGKONG
 EDDE | 98  | A__M_AZ_ON_ | AFRICA | AF DOLLAR | CAPETOWN
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is what @k-five did.  Pro golfer!